# After comparing two csv files, how to print the different lines in spesific column. Using python or Bash

Tags: python, bash, awk

I have two csv files, which contains two columns for each one.

file1.csv

```
C2-C1 1.5183
C3-C2 1.49
C3-C1 1.4991
O4-C3 1.4104
C1-C2-C3 59.78
```

file2.csv

```
C2-C1 1.5052
C3-C2 1.505
C3-C1 1.5037
S4-C3 1.7976
C1-C2-C3 59.95
```

I print in the output file three column:
column-1: the similar lines, and then, the different lines

column-2 and column-3: values of the second column in file1.csv and file2.csv, respectively.

desired output.csv

```
C2-C1        1.5183   1.5052
C3-C2        1.49     1.505
C3-C1        1.4991   1.5037
C1-C2-C3     59.78    59.95
O4-C3        1.4104     -
S4-C3          -      1.7976
```

I tried with "itertools", I did not find a suitable format for the differences lines.

```
import itertools

files = ['1.csv', '2.csv']
d = {}

for fi, f in enumerate(files):
    fh = open(f)
    for line in fh:
        sl = line.split()
        name = sl[0]
        val = float(sl[1])
        if name not in d:
            d[name] = {}
        if fi not in d[name]:
            d[name][fi] = []
        d[name][fi].append(val)
    fh.close()

for name, vals in d.items():
    if len(vals) == len(files):
        for var in itertools.product(*vals.values()):
            if max(var) - min(var) <= 20:
                out1 = '{}\t{}'.format(name, "\t".join(map(str, var)))
                print(out1)
                break


for name, vals in d.items():
    if len(vals) != len(files):
        for var in itertools.product(*vals.values()):
            if max(var) - min(var) <= 20:
                out2 = '{}\t{}'.format(name, "\t".join(map(str, var)))
                print(out2)
                break
```

my output:

```
C2-C1   1.5183  1.5052
C3-C2   1.49    1.505
C3-C1   1.4991  1.5037
C1-C2-C3    59.78   59.95
O4-C3   1.4104
S4-C3   1.7976
```

Comment: Can you put the output of your code also

Comment: I added my output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following `awk` may help you on same, this could take care of duplicate items too in Input_file(s).

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
   a[$1]=$2;
   next}
NF{
   printf("%s %s %s\n",$1,$1 in a?a[$1]:"-",$2);
   b[$1]=$1 in a?$1:""
}
END{
   for(i in a){
     if(!b[i] || b[i]==""){  print i,a[i],"-"  }}
}' file1.csv file2.csv | column -t
```

Comment: Remember that a non-parenthesized ternary expression **WILL** cause errors in some awks in some contexts. Always do `( x ? y : z)`, not just `x ? y : z` for portability plus it helps readability. Also, print and printf are  builtins, not functions, so the round brackets don't do what you think they do (but probably are harmless though unnecessary). You also don't need `;`s at the end of every line. So for example `printf("%s %s %s\n",$1,$1 in a?a[$1]:"-",$2);` should be written `printf "%s %s %s\n",$1,($1 in a?a[$1]:"-"),$2`

Comment: i think `if (!b[i]` is wrong. Why would you treat `b[i] == 0` differently than other values?

Answer (score 2):

A pure Python solution, and can work with as many files as needed (it will add a new column for each file and sort based on number of files sharing the same first column value). As a bonus, it actually uses proper CSV parsing so it could handle multiple CSV formats with little to no alteration:

```
import csv

files = ["1.csv", "2.csv"]  # as many files as you want

results = []  # a store for our final result
line_map = {}  # store a map for a quick update lookup
for i, f in enumerate(files):  # enumerate the file list and iterate over it
    with open(f, newline="") as f_in:  # open(f, "rb") on Python 2.x
        reader = csv.reader(f_in, delimiter=" ") # proper CSV reader, assumed space delimiter
        for row in reader:  # iterate over the current CSV line by line
            row_id = row[0]  # extract the first column for easier access
            if row_id not in line_map:  # a column value encountered for the first time...
                line_map[row_id] = [row_id] + ["-"] * len(files)  # create a placeholder list
                results.append(line_map[row_id])  # add the value on its own column
            line_map[row[0]][i+1] = row[1]  # save the value in its place in the results list
# now we need to bracket the results in order of number of values before writing
# the easiest way is to just sort based on the amount of blank spaces
results = sorted(results, key=lambda x: x.count("-"))
```

Now, if you just want to print it:

```
for r in results:
    print("\t".join(r))
# C2-C1 1.5183  1.5052
# C3-C2 1.49    1.505
# C3-C1 1.4991  1.5037
# C1-C2-C3  59.78   59.95
# O4-C3 1.4104  -
# S4-C3 -   1.7976
```

Or if you want to actually save it to a properly formatted CSV file:

```
with open("output.csv", "w", newline="") as f:  # open(f, "wb") on Python 2.x
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter="\t")  # a proper CSV writer, tab used as a delimiter
    writer.writerows(results)
```

Comment: thank you very much @zwer. Thank you for your time ... and also for the comments of each line

Answer (score 2):

GNU awk solution using 2d arrays, `ARGIND` and `column -t` for pretty printing. It supports more than two files:

```
$ awk '
{ a[$1][ARGIND]=$2 }                                       # hash to 2d array
END {
    for(i in a) {                                          # iterate all a
        printf "%s",i                                      # output key
        for(j=1;j<=ARGIND;j++)                             # iterate all data in a
            printf "%s%s", OFS, (a[i][j]==""?"-":a[i][j])  # output
        print ""                                           # finish with a newline
    }
}' file1 file2 file1 file2 | column -t                     # pretty print 
C1-C2-C3  59.78   59.95   59.78   59.95
O4-C3     1.4104  -       1.4104  -
S4-C3     -       1.7976  -       1.7976
C3-C1     1.4991  1.5037  1.4991  1.5037
C3-C2     1.49    1.505   1.49    1.505
C2-C1     1.5183  1.5052  1.5183  1.5052
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    file2[$1] = $2
    next
}
{
    print $0, ($1 in file2 ? file2[$1] : "-")
    delete file2[$1]
}
END {
    for (key in file2) {
        print key, "-", file2[key]
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file2.csv file1.csv | column -t
C2-C1     1.5183  1.5052
C3-C2     1.49    1.505
C3-C1     1.4991  1.5037
O4-C3     1.4104  -
C1-C2-C3  59.78   59.95
S4-C3     -       1.7976
```

Answer (score 1):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk 'NR == FNR{ a[$1] = $2; next }
     { 
         if ($1 in a) { print $1, $2, a[$1]; delete a[$1] }
         else a[$1] = $2 OFS "-"
     }
     END{ 
         for (i in a) print  i, (a[i] ~ /-$/ ? a[i] : "-" OFS a[i]) 
     }' file2.csv file1.csv | column -t
```

The output:

```
C2-C1     1.5183  1.5052
C3-C2     1.49    1.505
C3-C1     1.4991  1.5037
C1-C2-C3  59.78   59.95
O4-C3     1.4104  -
S4-C3     -       1.7976
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using pandas it'll make the life much easier:

```
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.DataFrame({'num01':[1.5183,1.49,1.4991,1.4104,59.78]},
                  index=['C2-C1','C3-C2','C3-C1','O4-C3','C1-C2-C3'])
df2=pd.DataFrame({'num02':[1.5183,1.49,1.4991,1.4104,59.78]},
                  index=['C2-C1','C3-C2','C3-C1','S4-C3','C1-C2-C3'])
df=pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1).replace('nan','-')
```

You can read your csvs into pandas easily and don't have to deal with awk codes.

```
index   num01   num02
C1-C2-C3    59.78   59.78
C2-C1   1.5183  1.5183
C3-C1   1.4991  1.4991
C3-C2   1.49    1.49
O4-C3   1.4104  -
S4-C3   -   1.4104
```

Answer (score 0):

A Python `defaultdict` could do the trick, provided the default value is a list of n values:

```
files = ['1.csv', '2.csv']
d = collections.defaultdict(lambda x: ['-'] * len(files))

for fi, f in enumerate(files):
    with open(f) as fd:
        for line in fh:
            sl = line.split()
            name = sl[0]
            val = float(sl[1])
            d[name][fi] = val

fmt = "{:<12}" + "{:<12}" * len(files)
for k, val in d.items():
    print(fmt.format(k, *val))
```